# EntityFramework ModelBuilder: Help building a class that contains two lists of a second class

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Trying to implement the fluid api approach for tabulating c# classes, but am struggling with building a model. From a database first approach, I would like to have three tables. The first(bay) containing a primary key, a second(boxes1) containing a foreign key, and a third(boxes2) containing a foreign key. Functionally I have 'i' number of Bays in my code that will contain 'j' and 'k' number of Boxes.

```
public class BayContext : DbContext
{
    public BayContext() : base(new DbContextOptions<BayContext>())
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Bay> Bays { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Bay>()
            .HasKey(pg => pg.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Box>()
            .HasOne(g => g.Bay)
            .WithMany(g => g.Boxes1)
            .HasForeignKey(g => g.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Box>()
            .HasOne(g => g.Bay)
            .WithMany(g => g.Boxes2)
            .HasForeignKey(g => g.Id);
    }
}

public class Bay
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = default(int);
    public string col1 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string col2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public virtual List<Box> Boxes1 { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Box> Boxes2 { get; set; }
}

public class Box
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = default(int);
    public int BoxNum { get; set; } = 0;
    public string col2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

build your tables in sql than use power tools for visual studio to reverse engineer the tables in an entity framework model.  You should let the tool discover all the database constraints and indexes and foreign keys for you.  Manually coding fluent is a bad idea.

Comment: What if I only posted the two classes, Bay and Box. Then asked how do I use ORM to put them into sql server?

Comment: Yes.  Power tools will create the sql scripts to generate the tables on the db